# Mysql эквивалент bit-literals

Tags: mysql, битовые-операции

Как в MySql получить эквивалент записи вида: b'0101'
если строка - результат другой операции, например: CONCAT('01','01') ?

Перепробовал кучу вариантов, но не получилось.
Ниже в запросе это почти удалось...  почти.

```
SELECT b'0101', CONV(CONCAT('01','01'),2,16)

05, 5
```

В первом случае получается бинарная срока, во втором десятичное число.

Comment: Ваше '05' в примере меня смутило. я думал оно число возвращает, а фактически символ с заданным кодом. Если один байт - то используйте функцию `char()` подавая ей на вход десятичное значение.

Comment: О, еще вариант придумал, `unhex()` от 16-ричного значения. он многобайтовый

Comment: Похоже получилось. Благодарю! Только выглядит довольно страшно: unhex(CONV(CONCAT('10111011','1'),2,16)). Было бы здорово одним действием интерпретировать строку как последовательность битов.

Comment: *Было бы здорово одним действием интерпретировать строку как последовательность битов.* `CREATE FUNCTION`